# Using explicit type conversion in C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2013

I was trying to develop a Silverlight application using Visual studio 2013. I am a beginner in this. I have an implicit type conversion in the below code.

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    Page p = new Page();
    this.RootVisual = p;

    // This assumes that Page.LayoutRoot exists and is a StackPanel.
    StackPanel layoutRoot = p.LayoutRoot;

    // Display the custom initialization parameters.
    foreach (String key in e.InitParams.Keys)
    {
           layoutRoot.Children.Add(new TextBlock()
        {
            Text = String.Format(
                "from InitParams: {0} = {1}", key,
                e.InitParams[key])
        });
    }

    // Display the URL parameters.
    foreach (String key in HtmlPage.Document.QueryString.Keys)
    {
        layoutRoot.Children.Add(new TextBlock()
        {
            Text = String.Format(
                "from QueryString: {0} = {1}", key,
                HtmlPage.Document.QueryString[key])
        });
    }
```

When i compile the code, I am getting the error

```
 " Error    1    Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' to 'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel'
```

How can I make this explicit function?

Comment: What is `p.LayoutRoot`?

Comment: you can't explicitly cast them - they are different types!

Comment: `StackPanel layoutRoot = p.LayoutRoot;` is your problem ... your layout root in the xaml is obviously a Grid, and you are trying to cast it to a StackPanel. This isn't possible. Change your xaml, or change your code.

Comment: Hi all, Thanks for the replies. Actually I am trying to achieve this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189004%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file `Page.xaml`, find the `Grid` with the x:Name "LayoutRoot" and replace it with a `StackPanel` (with the same x:Name)

Comment: Hi Martin, This is my code
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/293c928eec2801f28502 . So, the Stackpanel already exists. Can I replace it then?

Comment: @Unnikrishnan: I looked at your code ...and saw the problem, you have a Grid there with x:Name="LayoutRoot" and a StackPanel with Name="layoutRoot". So... remove the x:Name attribute from the Grid and rename the StackPanel to x:Name="LayoutRoot" (and yes, the x: is important if you want to use the name from code-behind)